# Use listener event to call function within the same cog using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to use a listener event to activate a function I have in a cog using `discord.py`. This same code functions properly in the main bot.py file (removing `self` and using `@client.event` instead of a listener) but when used in the cog, it tells me that the `repeater()` function is an undefined variable when being used in the listener event

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
    
class Repeater(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @tasks.loop(seconds = 10)
    async def repeater(self):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(834554679265329172)
        await channel.send('test')
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        repeater.start()
    
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Repeater(client))
```

EDIT:

So I changed the code match this after a comment recommended it, and the console throws this error

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    self.repeater()
```

```
> discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.repeater'
> raised an error: TypeError: Cog.listener expected str but received
> 'function' instead.
```

EDIT 2:

Changed the code to match this, and it will run the loop exactly one time, but doesn't actually loop

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    await self.repeater()
```

Comment: `self.repeater` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class you have to use `self.` to access its method `self.repeater` and `self.repeater.start()`

I tested it on this code and it works for me.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import datetime

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
CHANNEL = 834554679265329172

class Repeater(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def repeater(self):
        #channel = self.client.get_channel(CHANNEL)
        await self.channel.send(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("It's %H:%M.%S"))
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.channel = self.client.get_channel(CHANNEL)
        
        print('starting repeater')
        self.repeater.start()
    
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Repeater(client))

# --- main ---
    
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
setup(client)

print('starting bot')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

`repeater` is a function of the class. So you can call it with `self.repeater`. And to start a discord task use start attribute. `self.repeater.start()` is the answer.

Comment: when using `self.repeater.start()` I get the error "Method 'repeater' has no 'start' member"